# How to set cell value dependent on another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got a strange task to perform and I can't imagine how to do it or even come up with a term to google, since I'm not that good with excel formulas.

If the number in cell 'B6' (20.00) is in the column "c" the following needs to be done

Go to column 'E' and position itself in the same row that contains the number 20.00 (in this case E21).

[image: ill add an image so its easier to understand]

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Explain more.

Comment: Like... when you click on B6 you want to jump to E21?